# Anchor fails when executing .exe at a different path

Tags: winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have a form with some controls that are positioned with the Anchor Property.
I Debug AND Release Mode it works fine, but when I copy the `.exe` to another place and execute it there it fails.

This only happens for this one special form, all other forms of the project work... I hope that someone ran into that earlier

EDIT: It's bad said: The anchor positioning does not work properly

Comment: This makes no sense. Clean your entire project, delete all copies laying around, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I found it and I post it here in case someone else is also trapped by that:

**Copy all resource dlls and everything else that is produced by the Compiler along with the .exe**